# Determine Whether Index of a String Contains a Character

Tags: java, string, boolean, character

I'm looking to be able to tell if a String's index contains any character; for the reason to avoid an *StringIndexOutOfBoundsException*.

Currently what I have setup is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < largestLeng; i++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < wordRay.length; n++)
    {
        stringTemp = wordRay[n];
        stringTempRev = new StringBuilder(stringTemp).reverse().toString();
        if (stringTempRev.charAt(i) == true)
        {
            output += stringTempRev.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    output += "\n";
}
```

There may be an easy way to solving this, though currently I've hit a brick wall. I've been searching whether Java can "except" or "pass" an error (as some variants of Python include). Though I'm not very sure on the topic.

Thanks for your help.

---

**Edit**

This was in response to a class lab of mine that I was trying to complete, and this is the sample data given:

```
2003 TCEA STATE CONTEST
```

To where it's supposed to be outputted as this:

```
TEA3
STE0
EAC0
TTT2
NS
O
C
```

My problem was not being able to determine "whether a String had an index passed the amount of characters incorporated;" because some of the words given vary in length.

This was easily fixable by a solution I overlooked; provided by @dasblinkenlight.

Comment: does `if (index < string.length()) {...}` work?

Comment: `if (stringTempRev.charAt(i) == true)` what do you think happens here?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It does not work, though maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: And @sam, I was hoping that it would return whether there was a character at the index "n."

Comment: @Saroekin there is _always_ a character at any index within the String's length.  There's not empty space in the middle of a String.

Comment: What does the Javadoc for `charAt` say it does? Does it say "returns whether there's a character at the index 'n'"?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight My mistake, it did work. Couldn't figure out why for a second, though I've fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused on the purpose of reversing the string...

Comment: @cricket_007 It's for a class lab of mine, and that's one way I thought of doing it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for your answer, though I understand that. I mainly meant for it to tell whether a String had an index passed the amount of characters incorporated; because some of the words I'm testing vary in length.

Comment: Then you need to compare `i` to `string.length()`.

Comment: Can you update your question with the full description of your problem? When I see string reversal and character testing, I immediately think about palindromes.

Comment: @cricket_007 Sure, I'll take what the lab was prompting and describe my reasoning behind it.

Comment: @cricket_007 Added it in, hope it helps clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct or simplest fix (submitted by @dsblinkenlight) would be to obviously use:

```
if (index < string.length())
```

Rather than determining whether a String has a character at a specifically defined index (which I dismissed in a cursory manner).